# What is the best approach to learn magento2 as backend developer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, certification

I want to become a certified backend Magento developer in 6 months, what path should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fresher, I would suggest following this path
**1- Learn how** to create modules and database tables, insert values into them using data patches, and then display those values from the database.
**2- create a CRUD operation on the frontend**, which means creating a form on the frontend and then performing edit, delete and display inserted values by post listing.
**3- make a CRUD form in the admin grid side using UI components** and create massactions and actions fields.
**4- learn about service contracts** and apply service contract terminologies on the front-end form you created on the front-end, which means inserting and displaying data using API interface and repository patterns.
So far this is the basics you covered and do in mind to follow Magento coding standards like don't use deprecated code and using proper indentations and doc block commenting.
**5- learn about plugins and observers** and do some exercises on the storefront using plugins like changing colour or names, displaying specific products something like that
**6- learn cron jobs system configurations and how to override templates file**
so far this is enough to lend you a job as a Magento2 backend developer.
in case any questions let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think best way to become certified developer in 6 month,

1. Clear basic funda of php , crud operation , oops concept practically not theoretically.
2. take a deep dive in vendor all modules with override in your app/code or app/design.
3. contribute in stackoverflow or github with backend issue only.

Practice with all small small parts of magento everyday, if your base is clear than it's easy for certification.
I hope it'll help.
Thanks